# Do I need to Use an AlarmManager and WakeLock to periodically use a LocationClient?

Tags: android, location, alarmmanager, google-play, wakelock

Posts from over a year ago suggest that it is necessary to use a WakeLock to reserve CPU to gather location information (CommonsWare in particular here [Android Periodic GPS location updates with AlarmManager inside a Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869153/android-periodic-gps-location-updates-with-alarmmanager-inside-a-service)). However I do not understand why I cannot simply call a Service every 28 minutes, connect the LocationClient, set a timer to wait 2 minutes, then get the most recent location, disconnect the client, and then stop the service.

Because Commonsware and the user who forked his example here (https://github.com/alexbirkett/cwac-locpoll/blob/master/src/com/commonsware/cwac/locpoll/LocationPollerService.java) use a LocationListener, and not a LocationClient, I was wondering whether his answer still aplies.

Thanks for your time!

**EDIT:** Is it this simple, where an AlarmManager calls a Service every 28 minutes > the Service acquires a WakeLock and a timer elapses for two minutes as the LocationClient is connect > once two minutes has elapsed, I can kill the service and release the WakeLock?

It would look something like this:

```
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
    wl.acquire();

    Timer theTimer = new Timer();
    theTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(checkIfGooglePlay()) {
                getPostLocation();
                w1.release();
                stopSelf(); 
            }
        }
    }, TWO_MINUTES);

    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However I do not understand why I cannot simply call a Service every 28 minutes, connect the LocationClient, set a timer to wait 2 minutes, then get the most recent location, disconnect the client, and then stop the service.

You probably can poll the `LocationClient`. However, you will still need a `WakeLock`, as the device will fall asleep during those two minutes otherwise, you will still need `AlarmManager` for the "every 28 minutes" part, and I don't know if `LocationClient` will impose other requirements beyond those.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare thank you so much for this answer and the numerous others that have been so incredibly helpful! To be clear, I would not need to use a WakeLock for the every 28 minutes part? I would only need to use it for the every two minutes? Thanks again for everything

Comment: I have a followup question. The timer, even after acquiring the WakeLock, does not appear to work properly within my Service class. How would you recommend I give my LocationClient a two minute window to connect before polling the location?

Comment: @jsc123: "I would not need to use a WakeLock for the every 28 minutes part?" -- correct. "I would only need to use it for the every two minutes?" -- and to get control to the service. *If* you use a *broadcast* `PendingIntent`, *then* `AlarmManager` will wake up the device and keep it awake long enough for `onReceive()` to return. In `onReceive()`, you need to acquire a `WakeLock` and start your service. Your service needs to `release()` the `WakeLock` (reliably) when your work is done.

Comment: @jsc123: "How would you recommend I give my LocationClient a two minute window to connect before polling the location?" -- you could just use `AlarmManager`, calling `set()` to get control in two minutes. Or use `ScheduledExecutorService`.

Comment: thank you for your continued guidance. I am having a bit of difficulty implementing your recommendation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429961/service-calling-alarmmanager-on-another-service. I have the initial service call a new subclass (which has access to the LocationClient) after a two minute period. However it never gets successfully called.

Comment: Is it that wakelock is responsible for keeping the device on, and the AlarmManager is responsible for awaking the device from sleep ?

Comment: @ransh: Yes and yes.