# Android: Service to get and send GPS co-ordinates to server

Tags: android, gps, android-service, android-location

I know this is duplicate question, but I am not getting the explanatory example or solution.
I want to develop an application which after run calls a background service which takes the GPS location of device and send it via PHP web service to the server. And when user wants, he can stop the service.

I am working on service for the first time. I searched on google and found many tutorial, but not getting it.

So please guide me for this.

Comment: why use php yet you can use cloud service like parse for user location. http://parse.com

Comment: i need to send coordinated to my server.

Comment: are you sending lat long continuously to server,what you have tried?

Comment: where are you facing problem in doing so?

Answer (score 0):

you can able to send current location or lat and lag point into your server using webservice

frequently you want to update your location or lat and lag use handler

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed( new Runnable() {

 @Override
 public void run() {
handler.postDelayed( this, 60 * 1000 );
 }
}, 60 * 1000 );
```

Comment: Mr.Lazy coward down voter,give the comment  what i did  wrong here

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Location Tracking [Code Here](http://www.androidsourcehelp.com/2014/03/get-location-and-its-changes-in-android.html),

you need to run service with Timers or PendingIntents.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // getLocation From Here
        }
    };
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 60*1000);
```

Or

```
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mActivity,0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
        interval = 1 * 60 * 1000;   
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
        calendar.getTimeInMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
```

And you can get the Location Tracking with Service [Code Here](http://www.androidsourcehelp.com/2014/03/get-location-and-its-changes-in-android.html)

In this case you running a background service continuously. so battery will dry.