# How can i send data to server from android service?

Tags: android, networking, service

I creating app that watch user's location. I want to send every location update to server in background. I want to do this when app closed. I created a basic service. I can watch user location logging to console. But i stuck on communicate to server. How can i do this? Have a sample code?

Comment: check the answer of similar problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21762293/run-gps-as-background-service-and-send-coordinates-to-web-server-php

Comment: Thanks @CharefEddineMechalikh.  Well, have an alternative for http? e. websocket..