# Geolocation when device goes idle

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-alloy

My appcelerator app on iOS and Android requires getting the latest Geolocation every 5 seconds and sending the location back to a server.

It works well when the app is on and the screen is on, however on both platforms when the screen goes off the geolocation object doesn't appear to get updated very often - so even if I get the geolocation every 5 seconds it's not accurate.

How can I get the geolocation to regularly update when the phone screen is off?

Comment: Try checking out this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21762293/run-gps-as-background-service-and-send-coordinates-to-web-server-php/21763366#21763366

Comment: Thanks @AtishAgrawal - I created a background service. It runs but as soon as the screen goes off it no longer gets geolocation data. Any ideas?

Comment: You must be missing wakelock. Check for it. Also, please do check whether your service is running in the background or not?

Comment: I have WakeLock set. the app still outputs to the console log every 5 seconds so I know it's still running. It's that the geolocation object doesn't update with a new location.

Comment: can you share some code so that we can see what are you missing? It will help us to diagnose better

Answer (score 1):

You should request geolocation in foreground `Intent Service` in other case it will not work on Android O with 5 seconds accuracy.

Also you should use `WakeLock` to prevent sleep mode.

Comment: Thanks @DEADMC I'll play with wakelock. Are you saying even with wakelock I won't be able to achieve 5 second accuracy with Android O? Is there something in the OS that will prevent me from achieving it?

Comment: @EngWeiChua right now WakeLock will give you 5 sec accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to get the location every 5 seconds while the device is off?  That will drain the battery very quickly.  I think every 5 to 10 *minutes* would be more appropriate.  And maybe even that is excessive.

If what you really need is regular, periodic updates to position, I would suggest the following two solutions:

- ios: set Ti.Geolocation.trackSignificantLocationChange to true; if your app was killed by the OS, it will be relaunched on significant location changes; you can detect this situation using the launchOptionsLocationKey of the Ti.App.getArguments()
- android: implement a background service (https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android.Service) to check the location

Note: for android, we found that the OS would kill our service periodically, and while it always scheduled it to restart, sometimes, it would schedule that for a very long time out (e.g. 8 hours).  We ended up using an AlarmService (https://github.com/benbahrenburg/benCoding.AlarmManager) to periodically launch our background code (e.g. every 30 minutes), and the background code would shut itself down after about 25 minutes.

Also, if you care about your service starting back up after the device is rebooted, you should consider using a BootReceiver (https://github.com/benbahrenburg/benCoding.Android.Tools/) to restart the AlarmService.

Obviously, big props to Ben Bahrenburg for his excellent modules!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The app is not for consumers it's for a business to track the location of a person extremely accurately for liability reasons. 

On Android I implemented a background service. It gives me the location when the app is not in the foreground, however as soon as the screen goes off there's no location update events. This was happening on a Samsung S8.

I created a manual GPS location provider but as soon as the phone screen goes off the geolocation updates stop.

If I run this app, it works  GPS Keeper Lite. I don't know how it does it though!

Comment: We use a background service, and we are able to continuously get location updates (albeit at a much lower frequency than you are trying to  accomplish).  We don't get "events", though -- we call directly to `Ti.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()`

Answer (score 0):

There looks to be an fix coming out for this in 7.2.0

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-16066

There's also a 3rd party module that looks to solve the issue also

https://github.com/AppWerft/Ti.LocationUpdatesService

I've yet to try it however