# Check location in Alarm Manager

Tags: android, gps

I need to check current user location every 10 minutes even if user turned off the screen or closed app (not Force stop). For start of LocationCheckService I'm using AlarmService, but it's start to checking location always (onLocationChanged, for example). How to make only one request for location update every 10 minutes (without onLocationChanged every time) via Network or GPS provider?

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationCheckService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
        manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 100, 200, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

LocationCheckService.class

```
public class LocationCheckService extends Service {
    LocationManager locationManager = null;

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER));
        new Timer().schedule(new MyTimer(), 0, 10000);
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    class MyTimer extends TimerTask {
        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());

                List<Address> listAddress = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
                if (listAddress != null && listAddress.size() > 0)
                    Log.d(TAG, listAddress.get(0).getCountryCode());

                listAddress = geocoder.getFromLocation(1.3707295, 32.3032414, 1);
                if (listAddress != null && listAddress.size() > 0)
                    Log.d(TAG, listAddress.get(0).getCountryCode());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener {
        Location mLastLocation;

        public LocationListener(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
            mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
            mLastLocation.set(location);
        }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21762293/run-gps-as-background-service-and-send-coordinates-to-web-server-php/21763366#21763366

Comment: Step #1: Get rid of the `TimerTask`

Step #2: In `onLocationChanged()`, use the location that you receive, then call `removeLoccationUpdates()` (to stop getting updates) and `stopSelf()` (to stop the service).