# Android: Start my service when I close my app

Tags: android, service, background

Basically I have a service running to check my location every 30 minutes and when the location changes, pop up a basic notification. I only need this service when my app is closed (on stop/pause too). So im asking where should I start my service in my activity?

I want something similar as Facebook,Instagram and most of apps have... a service running from the background and when a notification pops up just open de app. While the app is open the service shouldnt do anything.

I tried onDestroy() method (in my MainActivity) but didnt work out, and onStop() method neither.

Do i explain myself?

Thanks!!

Comment: I don't think that is a good idea.I mean if somebody just opened-close or visa-versa your app your service idea won't be much helpful...

Comment: you can always run your service to fetch location ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recurring tasks should be scheduled using `AlarmManager` (or `JobScheduler`).

This is usually done in a `BroadcastReceiver` which reacts to `BOOT_COMPLETED`.

If you want to cancel such a job while your activity is active, call the respective methods on `AlarmManager` in `onResume` and `onPause`.

Comment: Thanks mate! I think this is the way. I've been looking and I found this post really interesting too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869153/android-periodic-gps-location-updates-with-alarmmanager-inside-a-service

Answer (score 0):

If you want your service to be running in the background at all times event after closing the app, you need to make your service `STICKY` and you can do that in the `OnStartCommand`

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);
    // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
    // stopped, so return sticky.
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Note that it returns `START_SICKY`  which tells the OS to recreate the service after it has enough memory and call onStartCommand() again with a null intent.

Read also about [application:persistent](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#persistent) which is "Whether or not the application should remain running at all times". This is more troublesome - System will try not to kill your app which will effect others in the system, you should be careful using it.